# CAS SSO with RegexRegisteredService and OidcRegisteredService

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, openid-connect

Short: **IT DOES NOT SSO**

Longer: I am trying to unite logins of two services via CAS (v5.0.4). I have configured the services and am now able to log into both. The problem is - **CAS is not acting as an SSO provider**. Logging into one of the services logs you in BUT you still have to enter your credentials for the second service (and vice versa). I suspect that I am missing some configuration options.

Here are my services:

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^(http|https)://service1.*",
  "name" : "service1",
  "id" : 12345678,
  "accessStrategy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
    "enabled" : true,
    "ssoEnabled" : true
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.OidcRegisteredService",
  "clientId": "client",
  "clientSecret": "secret",
  "serviceId" : "^https://service2.*",
  "signIdToken": true,
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
  "name": "OIDC",
  "id": 87654321,
  "evaluationOrder": 1,
  "attributeReleasePolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy"
  },
  "accessStrategy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
    "enabled" : true,
    "ssoEnabled" : true
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug in v5.0.x. Upgrading to v5.1.x fixes the issue.